# Closing question as duplicate of another question that has been put on hold

Tags: discussion, closing, close-reasons, duplicates

I think this has already been discussed somewhere, but I can't find where.

As an example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042993/topic-for-a-lecture-intended-for-high-school-students/) was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040544/interesting-piece-of-math-for-high-school-students). But the duplicate question was already been put on hold. I don't have a problem with the question(s) being closed/put on hold. (I think they would be a better fit for [matheducators.SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).)

But, as a principle, I think it is wrong to close a question as a duplicate of another question that is already been put on hold/closed, so I would suggest that we don't do that. I know that this might *seem* a bit pedantic, but I believe that we should try to pick the correct reasons for closing.

What say the community?

Comment: The second question mentioned above is not closed but put on hold (...pedantism$^{2}$).

Comment: @Did: Alright...

Comment: Building closed loops of closed duplicate (in particular unanswered) questions is inconsistent, their behavior is not predictable.

Comment: @Dilaton Question A cannot be closed as a duplicate of Question B unless B has an upvoted or accepted answer. And there is a check against forming closed loops, too.

Comment: I feel bad now because I voted to close as duplicate when there were 2 duplicate votes and 2 "too broad" votes

Comment: @Did: It is (and was) closed.  "On hold" is an artifact of the display logic -- a question which is closed for less than a certain time will be described as "on hold", after that time the description changes to "closed".  But the status has not changed.

Comment: Occasionally it might even happen that the duplicate link links to a deleted post or that there is a loop between duplicates. See
[What should I do when I find circularity among duplicates?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13249/what-should-i-do-when-i-find-circularity-among-duplicates) and
[Duplicate of a deleted question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15236/duplicate-of-a-deleted-question).

Answer (score 6):

In the specific question, I agree: closing as Too Broad would be better. If the question is edited, the case for reopening should be based on whether or not the author managed to
"add details to narrow the answer set", not on whether it is now sufficiently distinct from another Too Broad question. (I *think* I voted as too broad, but I may be wrong; in any case, the majority reason is the only one displayed.)

However, there are cases when it is appropriate to close as a duplicate of another closed question.

#### Double posts by the same author

Often, the   closing reason from the first copy  can still be used for the second. But what if the author than fixes both  versions and they no longer qualify for that reason? Both will be reviewed independently by Reopen reviewers, and probably reopened. Then the answers get split between the copies, until someone recognizes duplication and votes to close *again*...

Even when the second copy of a double post is not as bad as the first one, it is *still* a duplicate and should be closed. Users should be *editing* their on-hold questions, not  asking them again. If the moderators were not already overworked, I would suggest a nuclear solution to double posts: one-click deletion of the second copy.

#### Exact  duplicates closed as a abstract duplicate

Someone asks for a solution of $x^5-1=0$. There is already an **answered** question  A about $x^5-1=0$, closed as an abstract duplicate of  question B about $x^n-1=0$. In this case, I would vote to close as a duplicate of question A, since it is a closer match. The user is free to follow duplicate banner to question B from there, if the answers to A were not sufficient for any reason.